# how to update stage based on task completion?

Tags: apex, trigger, opportunity

i am trying to update the Stage based upon the Task.Status = 'Actividad-Finalizada'..and it worked if i have only one Task but i wont work if there are more task on same Opportunity..

Please can anybody check what change needs to this below code..

```
trigger UpdateOppOnTaskComplete on Task (after insert, after update) {

Set<String> whatIDs = new Set<String>();

for (Task t : Trigger.new) {
    if(t.Status.equals('Actividad-Finalizada'))
        whatIDs.add(t.whatID);
}

List<Opportunity> opps = [SELECT Id, StageName, Probability, Compania__c, Type  FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =: whatIDs AND (Probability = 98 OR Probability = 40) AND (Type = 'Flujo de venta Estándar' OR Type = 'Flujo de venta No Estándar')];

//List<Opportunity> opps1 = [SELECT Id, StageName, Probability, Compania__c  FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =: whatIDs AND Probability = 40 AND Type = 'Flujo de venta No Estándar'];

for(Opportunity opp : opps){
    if(opp.compania__c.equals('abc') && opp.Type.equals('Flujo de venta Estándar')){
        opp.StageName = 'Orden de Trabajo en proceso (99%)';
        opp.Probability = 99;
    }else if(opp.compania__c.equals('cdf')) {
        opp.StageName = 'Cerrada (100%)';
        opp.Probability = 100;
    }
    if(opp.compania__c.equals('abc') && opp.Type.equals('Flujo de venta No Estándar')){
        opp.StageName = 'Producto define precio final (42 %)';
        opp.Probability = 42;
    }
}
if(opps != null && opps.Size() > 0)
update opps;
}`
```

Comment: In what way is it not working if there's more than one Task? Your variable `whatIds` is a set, so that reduces the tasks to a single opportunity. Is there an issue with the opp not advancing two stages because of a task being filtered out?

Comment: yes. actually have an issue with multiple task...when first task to be completed then automatically stage set as 42% but what i am expecting is when second task will complete then at that time stage must have to change from 40 to 42 itself..

Comment: I'm not certain I quite follow you. Are you saying that you have situations where multiple tasks need to be completed before an opportunity can move from one stage to the next?

Comment: yes. exactly it wont allow if Task (open activities) are open

Comment: You lost me again. If a Task is open of type you're looking for, perhaps the Opp shouldn't be moved forward? Issue may be that you've not been specific enough in sorting tasks on correct fields. Be clear on what your criteria are. Edit your post to explain your criteria when there's more than one task. Is there another field on the task which signifies that the opp should be moved forward upon completion or do several tasks need to be completed before that can happen? That's still unclear. If it takes several, there needs to be a counter on Opp with it that's decremented as they're closed.

Comment: See, there is one Opportunity..that opportunity have two Open activities..Now what i expecting is once these both Open activities get completed (or You can say Task.Status = 'Actividad-Finalizada') then Stage must have to set as 42%.. Hope it's clear NOW....Thanks

Comment: Hey crmprogdev, it's done....Thanks for your time :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
trigger UpdateOppOnTaskComplete on Task (after insert, after update) {

Set<String> whatIDs = new Set<String>();

for (Task t : Trigger.new) {
    if(t.Status.equals('Actividad-Finalizada'))
        whatIDs.add(t.whatID);
}

List<Opportunity> opps = [SELECT Id, StageName, Probability, Compania__c, Type FROM Opportunity WHERE Id =: whatIDs AND (Probability = 98 OR Probability = 40) AND (Type = 'Flujo de venta Estándar' OR Type = 'Flujo de venta No Estándar')];

Integer tskCount = 0;

for(Opportunity opp : opps){

    if(opp.compania__c.equals('abc') && opp.Type.equals('Flujo de venta Estándar')){
        opp.StageName = 'Orden de Trabajo en proceso (99%)';
        opp.Probability = 99;
    }else if(opp.compania__c.equals('cdf')) {
        opp.StageName = 'Cerrada (100%)';
        opp.Probability = 100;
    }
    if(opp.compania__c.equals('abc') && opp.Type.equals('Flujo de venta No Estándar')){
        List<AggregateResult> opentsk =[SELECT Count(Id)countTask FROM Task WHERE IsClosed=false and WhatId =: opp.id];
        tskCount=(Integer)opentsk[0].get('countTask');
        opp.StageName = 'Producto define precio final (42 %)';
        opp.Probability = 42;
    }
}
if(tskCount == 0)
update opps;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your posted answer isn't bulkified and could easily wind up failing with an exception of 
`System.LimitException: Too many SOQL queries: 101` because of the `AggregrateResult` query inside your last `If` statement.

```
Integer tskCount = 0;

for(Opportunity opp : opps){

    ....

    if(opp.compania__c.equals('abc') && opp.Type.equals('Flujo de venta No Estándar')){
        List<AggregateResult> opentsk =[SELECT Count(Id)countTask FROM Task WHERE IsClosed=false and WhatId =: opp.id];
        tskCount=(Integer)opentsk[0].get('countTask');
        opp.StageName = 'Producto define precio final (42 %)';
        opp.Probability = 42;
    }
}
if(tskCount == 0)
update opps;
}
```

Further, I have issues with your use of the variable `Integer tskCount`. You only change it's value each time you run the `AggregrateResult` query. The value of that variable isn't decremented nor incremented anyplace in your code. It could be a value of something other than zero during one of the loops. As long as the final time it goes through that last `If` statement during a loop it's value is set to zero, your trigger will set `tskCount` to zero and allow your code to update your opportunities when it exits your `for loop`.

Now, what happens if `tskCount != 0`? There's no update of the opportunities and your code simply exits without performing any updates! This is NOT a good thing. This is where your trigger needs to be reporting an error instead. In fact, code to make that happen should probably be written inside the `if` statement where where you set `tskCount=(Integer)opentsk[0].get('countTask');` It's at that point where if the `tskCount` isn't equal to `zero` that you'll want to use the `addError()` method. See [Trigger Exceptions](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_triggers_exceptions.htm?search_text=adderror) and also [sObject addError(errorMsg)](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_sobject.htm#apex_System_SObject_addError).

If you don't want to use the `All or None` attributes for your updates, you can allow `partial` updates and report the error messages via some kind of error handler, whether it be through the debug log or preferably through some other means like an email to the admin. See [Returned Database Errors](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_dml_database_error.htm) for some of the basics on exception handling as a starting point.

Your code as written has numerous issues that really need to addressed before releasing it into production.